# docker compose MySQL container [2002] Connection refused

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker

I'm trying to build docker compose containers for Nginx + PHP(Laravel) + MySQL, but I keep getting Connection refused error

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:

    nginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - '8080:80'
        volumes:
            - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            - ./logs/nginx:/var/logs/nginx
            - ./apps:/var/www/html
        depends_on:
            - php
        restart: always

    php:
        image: laradock/php-fpm:2.2-7.2
        volumes:
            - ./apps:/var/www/html
        restart: always
    mysql:
        image: mariadb
        ports:
            - '33060:3306'
        volumes:
            - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
        restart: always
```

In `./apps` I have a brand new Laravel app with basic SQL setup

All containers run without errors, and I can connect to the MySQL container using

```
mysql -u 127.0.0.1 -P 33060 -u root -p
```

but I keep getting error 2002 when I try to access from the browser or direct ssh into php container.

I have nginx and mysql running on the server so I use 8080 and 33060 port, not sure if that's the problem.

**.env**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I suspect that your laravel app is trying to reach mysql via port 3306 while it is exposed as 33060 by mysql container. Make sure php app is configured to use port 33060 for mysql connection.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

getting idea from [this Github Issue](https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/320)

> My first guess is that it is dying trying to find the mysql unix
> socket file, when it needs to be connecting over a non-localhost
> connection. If you are using the compose file to start them, then you
> can connect to the dns name provided by docker (ie, links:
> docker-mysql, sets the dns name to be docker-mysql). So you have to
> change your connection line:
>
> `- php -r "new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;charset=utf8', 'root', '123123');"`
>
> `+ php -r "new PDO('mysql:host=docker-mysql;port=3306;charset=utf8', 'root', '123123');"`

solved this by changing the `DB_HOST` to the docker container name in `.env` file

```
DB_HOST=docker_mysql_1
```

Comment: I'he been looking for answer 2 hours, thanks a lot =)