# Mysql on docker gives "Connection refused" error

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker-compose, laravel-8, connection-refused

I created my Laravel project with docker-compose. I created a database called fhblog in my local. When I enter the php container and run the `php artisan migrate` command, I get the following error.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = fhblog and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

I searched for the solution to the problem and followed the people's suggestions, but the error could not be solved.

**My .env  file**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=fhblog
DB_USERNAME=fhblog
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

**My mysql container**

```
  .
  .
  .
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: fhblog
      MYSQL_USER: fhblog
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - ./docker/mysql/db:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./docker/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - app-network
  .
  .
  .
```

In my research, it was recommended to run the `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan config:clear` commands, as they can remain in the "cache". These commands did not solve my problem either. Where is the error?

Comment: There are many duplicates here - for `DB_HOST` you need to use the name of your container, `mysql` in your case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [docker compose MySQL container \[2002\] Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50325230/docker-compose-mysql-container-2002-connection-refused)

Comment: I tried what you said but it didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should use the internal ip of mysql instead of container name;
login to the mysql container and run bash
then type ifconfig
probably your ip address is something like this

```
172.0.0.23
```

copy that and paste it in front of

```
DB_HOST=
```

but first of all try using container name as your

```
DB_HOST=mysql
```

or even rename it to something other than mysql

for example mysql_container

```
container_name: mysql_container
...
DB_HOST=mysql_container
```

Comment: Your first answer helped to solve my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I tried my mysql IP before. When I got a connection refused error on DBeaver, it gave me an IP address of 17.23.0.1. I thought this was my mysql IP and tried it this way. I wanted to look at my container IPs and tried the following command. The IP that came out was different. With this IP, I was finally able to run the `php artisan migrate` code.

```
docker inspect -f '{{.Name}} - {{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' $(docker ps -aq)
```

Later I realized that it was unnecessary. If I give the container name directly, my problem is handled more neatly.

```
DB_HOST=db
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a computer with a macos system you change the 3306 port to different port, the problem is solved.